# standard for loop: "'i' was not declared in this scope"

Tags: loops, for-loop

I don't understand what mistake I am making. The error I get is the same as in the title.

Please help me spot the problem.

```
#include <iostream>

void main() {
    for (i=1; i<=100; i = i+1) {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Alright, I see. Can it be that in 2008 you didn't have to declare `for`-loop variables? Because the book that I am working with does *not* declare `i` in the `for` loop!

Comment: Answer is the same as in the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you forgot to declare the variable i

```
int i = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You initialized `i` but didn't declare it, change `i=1` to:

```
int i=1
```

---

*Regarding your edit:*

No way. C used to be a strongly typed language and still is. Before you can access variables, you must declare them. And you should initialize them aswell. Because if you don't, you will get unexpected results, such as Segmentation Faults or some "random" (don't use them as a random number generator!) values.

Answer (score -1):

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i = i + 1)
```

Answer (score -1):

Allright i see. Can it be that in 2008 you didnt have to declare the variable in the for loop? Because my book that im working it does not declare the i variable in the for loop!

Comment: Even in 2008, you had to declare the index somewhere (In old-school C you couldn't declare it in the for statement but you had to declare if before that). And your "answer" should be a comment, or an edit to your question.